# validate nested object array with vuelidate

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I want to validate an object array inside nested object array

```
    FormData:Array[8]
    0:Object
        group:Object
            id:1
            cards:Array[8]
                0:Object
                id:2253
                    service:Object
                        name:"Service Name"
...
```

I need to validate from `service` only the `name`

I try with something like this, but no success...

```
validations() {
        return {
            FormData: {
                $each: {
                    group: {
                        cards: {
                            $each: {
                                service: {
                                    name: {
                                        required
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Seems like the `$each` is not working as i want to, what im doing wrong how can i get to correct nested object with `$each` ?